# Protocols {get set} : What does get and set allow and disallow in a protocol? Swift

Tags: swift

From online learning i learnt that get and set are functions that are called when you get or set a variable.  Eg

```
var test: String { 
       get{
         print("get called")
         return "default"
       }
       set{
       print("Set Called")
       }}
```

Where when test is called in code Eg something like

```
print(test)
```

it will execute the code in get{} and when test is being set as a value eg

```
test = "hello"
```

it calls the set{} code block

Now what I am trying to understand is why in a swift protocol when you put down what variables are needed for example

```
protocol Car {
   var make:String 
   var licenseNumber: Int
}
```

you need to have

```
protocol Car {
   var make:String { get set} 
   var licenseNumber: Int {get set}
}
```

or

```
protocol Car {
   var make:String {get}
   var licenseNumber: Int {get}
}
```

what I want to know is what does the get and set actually do and how is a protocol that has both

```
{get set}
```

different to

```
{get}
```

Comment: A protocol defines what is required to conform to it. So { get set } says that a type conforming to it must allow read and write access to that property. I would suggest you read up on protocol [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html)

Comment: This [post](https://medium.com/p/c69ed3cd5061) seems quite relevant to understand what get set property inside a protocol means

Answer (score 2):

Remember that protocols specifies a set of requirements - "things that conform to me have this and that ability", but not *how* they achieve those abilities.

This syntax:

```
var make: String
```

declares a *stored property* called `make`. Not only does it mean that "there should be a `String` property called `make` that you can get and set", but it also specifies *how* that property is implemented - namely that it is *stored* as part of the class/struct, as opposed to computed from other values. You can think of the above as syntactic sugar for:

```
var make: String 
// everything under this is the "how" part
// what actually happens is a little different - this is for illustrative purposes only
{
    get { return _make }
    set { _make = newValue }
}
private var _make: String
```

Clearly, protocol members are not supposed to do that.

This syntax

```
var make: String { get set }
```

on the other hand, declares no body (the "how" part) for the getter and setter, and so is valid in a protocol. It just says "there should be a `String` property called `make` that you can get and set", not saying anything about its implementation details. For example, in one implementation it could be computed from the `licenseNumber`:

```
// This implementation doesn't make much sense in real life. 
// The point is to show that you can implement the make property in many ways
// not just by *storing* the make
class MyCar: Car {
    var licenseNumber: Int

    var make: String {
        get {
            if licenseNumber == 1 {
                return "Make 1"
            } else {
                return "Make 2"
            }
        }

        set { // the setter doesn't have to set anything either
            print("The make is being set!")
        }
    }
}
```

And if you did `var make: String { get }` instead, the protocol only requires the property to be gettable (but of course implementations can also implement a setter if they want).

Answer (score 1):

The get/set in a protocol variable requirement have nothing to do with the computed property getter and setter functions you showed first.

The get/set in a protocol variable requirement simply states whether this variable is permitted to be read-only/constant (get) or must also be writable (get set).